# Is using mapM/sequence considered good practice?

Tags: haskell

Consider following example:

```
safeMapM f xs = safeMapM' xs []
    where safeMapM' []     acc = return $ reverse acc
          safeMapM' (x:xs) acc = do y <- f x
                                    safeMapM' xs (y:acc)

mapM return largelist      -- Causes stack space overflow on large lists
safeMapM return largelist  -- Seems to work fine
```

Using `mapM` on large lists causes a stack space overflow while `safeMapM` seems to work fine (using GHC 7.6.1 with `-O2`). However I was not able to find a function similar to `safeMapM` in the Haskell standard libraries.

Is it still considered good practice to use `mapM` (or `sequence` for that matter)?
If so, why is it considered to be good practice despite the danger of stack space overflows?
If not which alternative do you suggest to use?

Comment: Maybe `mapM` is faster if it doesn't overflow because you don't have to `reverse`? Did you measure it?

Comment: can you post the `Main` module you used to test?

Comment: Also, there are monads (like `Control.Monad.State.Lazy`) where something like `take 100 <$> mapM id [1..]` terminates. `take 100 <$> safeMapM id [1..]` cannot possibly terminate, regardless of the monad

Comment: @jberryman `main = mapM return [1..10000000] >> return ()`

Comment: @NiklasB. I am not proposing safeMapM as a better solution. In fact you showed a reason why not. But while mapM seems to be common it has the downside of a potential stack space overflow. My question is why or when (not) should we use mapM?

Comment: @jonny: If you have enough stack space to process the list? Remember that stack allocations might be cheaper and with `mapM` you don't need to reverse the list, so it might well be faster (I didn't measure it, though).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Niklas B., the semantics of `mapM` are those of an effectful right fold, and it terminates successfully in more cases than a flipped version. In general, `mapM` makes more sense, as it is rare that we would want to do a result-yielding map on an enormous list of data. More commonly, we'll want to evaluate such a list for *effects*, and in that case `mapM_` and `sequence_`, which throw away the results, are typically what are recommended.

Edit: in other words, despite the issue raised in the question, **yes**, `mapM` and `sequence` are commonly used and typically considered good practice.

Comment: I want my code to run in all cases, not just in "more cases". And a lot of effects come with return values e.g. user input. Niklas B. example I can catch while developing, stack space overflows with large lists might occur after deployment. Much more difficult to find imho

Comment: there are different semantics and different tradeoffs. so you need to pick the one that suits your situation. that's the answer! the only answer! the other code you provide also will fail on sufficiently large lists -- it will just take larger lists. you can also just add stack space to the program. just, you know, understand the tradeoffs and then make a choice.

Answer (score 7):

> If so, why is it considered to be good practice despite the danger of stack space overflows?
>   If not which alternative do you suggest to use?

If you want to process the list elements as they are generated, use either `pipes` or `conduit`.  Both will never build up an intermediate list.

I'll show the `pipes` way, since that is my library.  I'll first begin with an infinite list of numbers generated in the `IO` monad from user input:

```
import Control.Proxy

infiniteInts :: (Proxy p) => () -> Producer p Int IO r
infiniteInts () = runIdentityP $ forever $ do
    n <- lift readLn
    respond n
```

Now, I want to print them as they are generated.  That requires defining a downstream handler:

```
printer :: (Proxy p) => () -> Consumer p Int IO r
printer () = runIdentityP $ forever $ do
    n <- request ()
    lift $ print n
```

Now I can connect the `Producer` and `Consumer` using `(>->)`, and run the result using `runProxy`:

```
>>> runProxy $ infiniteInts >-> printer
4<Enter>
4
7<Enter>
7
...
```

That will then read `Int`s from the user and echo them back to the console as they are generated without saving more than a single element in memory.

So usually if you want an effectful computation that generates a stream of elements and consumes them immediately, you don't want `mapM`.  Use a proper streaming library.

If you want to learn more about `pipes`, then I recommend [reading the tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.1.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html).

Comment: This answer is a bit outdated. You may want to update it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stay in the lazy camp, the [lazyio](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lazyio) package allows you to process the input list lazily. Instead of

```
mapM f
```

you write

```
import qualified System.IO.Lazy as LazyIO

LazyIO.run . mapM (LazyIO.interleave . f)
```

No stack overflow anymore.